# JOIN tables with no direct relation

Tags: sql, ms-access

To practice SQL, I have created a testing database in MS Access. It stores information about a car shop's business. The layout is like so:

[image]

I have successfully built a query to `JOIN` the `repairs` table with `cars` and `services`:

```
SELECT cars.[Make], cars.[Year of production], services.[Service name]
FROM ( repairs 
INNER JOIN cars ON repairs.[Car number]=cars.[Car number] ) 
INNER JOIN services ON repairs.[Service ID]=services.ID
WHERE cars.[Color]='Red';
```

[image]

Now I would like to add customer info to that query, for instance display the information above AND customer's last name. However, seeing as there's no direct relation between `repairs` and `customers`, and I can't just `JOIN` these two tables, I'm at a loss as to how to build the query.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So join the table to `cars` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join tables that doesn't have a direct relation, you simply also join in the tables in between.

As you already have joined in the `cars` table that is in between, you can just join the `customers` to that. Rearrange the joins so that you get a chain from one end to the other:

```
SELECT
  cars.[Make], cars.[Year of production],
  services.[Service name],
  customers.[First Name], customers.[Last Name]
FROM
  (
    (
      services
      INNER JOIN repairs on repairs.[Service ID] = services.ID
    )
    INNER JOIN cars ON cars.[Car number] = repairs.[Car number]
  )
  INNER JOIN customers on customers.[ID] = cars.[Customer ID]
WHERE
  cars.[Color] = 'Red';
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take into account cars as well while joining, so your query would be :

```
SELECT cu.lastName
FROM ((customers cu INNER JOIN cars ca
ON cu.id = ca.customerId)
INNER JOIN replairs r
ON r.carNumber = ca.carNumber)
```

Comment: The principle is correct, but you can only join two tables in MS Access. You need to nest the joins using parentheses.

Comment: Ahh thanks i missed that! thought i was answering for mysql :)